# Swagger for Play: DELETE request always returns "Invalid Json"

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, swagger-ui

I've just downloaded the last distro of Swagger-UI... and it looks like it no longer works when sending a DELETE request without JSON body – be aware that this worked fine with the previous version. Here below are my annotations:

```
@ApiOperation(
  httpMethod = "DELETE",
  nickname = "delete",
  value = "Deletes an user",
  response = classOf[Void])
@ApiResponses(Array(
  new ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid user id"),
  new ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Request not authorized"),
  new ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "User does not have required privileges"),
  new ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User not found"),
  new ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "Authentication precondition failed"),
  new ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Error processing delete user request")))
def delete(
  @ApiParam(
    name = "userId",
    value = "The id of the user to delete",
    required = true)
    @PathParam("userId")
    userId: String) = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
  ...
}
```

Whenever I send a DELETE request, I always get the the following response (Bad request):

```
For request 'DELETE /auth/users/5392238c1e04001e04b384b4' [Invalid Json]
```

Again, I haven't modified my source code and if I rollback to the previous version of Swagger-UI it works as expected. Am I missing something? In case is there a workaround to make it work?

Comment: My body doesn't contain any data since I just sent the id of the user to delete in the URL. Why should I send Json data in a DELETE request? Maybe I don't get the point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Swagger UI distribution. The latest version fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still have problems with this, but I also had an issue with invalid Json when sending a DELETE request via swagger.

I fixed this in the code by adding a line in the swagger.js. In swagger.js there is a method called `SwaggerRequest.prototype.setHeaders`. In my version this is around line 1221 (can be a different one for you because I altered some other code as well).
In this method there should be a statement

```
else if (this.type == "DELETE")
  body = "{}";
```

I changed this into the following

```
else if (this.type == "DELETE") {
  body = "{ }";
  params.body = body;
}
```

Then if I do a delete via the swagger I don't get the Invalid Json anymore.

Comment: Yes... this was a bug and has been fixed. Just get the latest version from GitHub. Thanks anyway ;-)